# Show that an estimation procedure can be consistent without being unbiased or asymptotically unbiased.

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation, parameter-estimation

Problem statement: "To show that an estimator can be consistent without being unbiased or even asymptotically unbiased, consider the following estimation procedure: To estimate the unknown mean, $\mu$ of a population with the finite variance $\sigma^2$, we first take a random sample of size $n$. Then we randomly draw one of $n$ slips of paper numbered from $1$ through $n$, and if the number we draw is $2, 3,\ldots$ or $n$, we use as our estimator the mean of the random sample, $\bar X$; otherwise, we use the estimate $n^2$. Show that the estimation procedure is consistent and neither unbiased nor asymptotically unbiased."

I have figured out the following:

$E[X^*|2,3,\ldots,n]=E[\bar X]=\mu$

$E[X^*|1]=E[n^2]=n^2$

$E[X^*]=E[\bar X]\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}+E[n^2]\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\mu\frac{n-1}{n}+n^2\frac{1}{n}$ by the law of total expectation. 
Thus, $X^*$ is neither unbiased or asymptotically unbiased since the expected value is not equal to $\mu$ and the limit as $n$ approaches infinity is not equal to $0$.

I am not sure how to show that the procedure is consistent. Any suggestions on a starting place?

Comment: For big $n$, with high probability, $X^*=\overline X\,\dots$

Comment: You know when -by definition- an estimator is consistent?

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, I need to show for all c, P(|X* - $\mu$| < c) = 1. But my issue is figuring out what to do with that expression because I don't have a PDF to use. I only have expected values.

Comment: The strategy behind this estimator is that as you pick larger samples, the chance of your estimate being close to the parameter increases, but if you are unlucky, the estimate is **really** bad; it has to be bad enough to more than compensate for the small chance of picking it.  Such an estimator will have a bias that worsens with increasing sample size, yet it is consistent because you can make the probability of being unlucky as small as you please by choosing a sufficiently large sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the estimator of the paramenter $\mu$ , $A_\epsilon$ be the unfortunate event of having $|Y - \mu| \ge  \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$.

First a little of intuition: we know that the sample mean $Y_1=\bar X$ is a good (consistent) estimator (weak law of large numbers). Hence, we know that, if we used that estimator, $\displaystyle P(A_\epsilon) \to 0$ as ${n\to\infty}$. The problem here is that sometimes we don't use that nice estimator, but a ridiculously bad one ($Y_2=n^2$); fortunately, the bad estimator is used rarely, and more rarely as $n$  grows. Is this enough to (asympotically) dismiss it, and assert that we have a good estimator? Let's see.

Let $Z$ be the indicator value of the event that we draw the number 1 ($Z=1$ if we had to used the bad estimator, $Z=0$ otherwise).

$$ \begin{align}
P(A_\epsilon) &=  \sum P(A_\epsilon , Z)   \\ 
& = P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=1) P(Z=1)+P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=0) P(Z=0)\\
& = P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=1) \frac{1}{n}+P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=0) \frac{n}{n-1}
\end{align}$$

We want the left side to tend to zero. Now, we know the term $P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=0)$ tends to zero (because of what we said above), hence the problematic term is $P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=1)$ which can be quite high...  but not higher than $1$ (no?)

Hence we can bound

$$P(A_\epsilon) \le \frac{1}{n} + P(A_\epsilon \mid Z=0)$$

Because both terms on the right side tend to zero, so does the left side.